# Iterate through array of column names to pass to uniq.pluck()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have multiple columns I need to pull unique values from and compile an array of each unique value. Using uniq.pluck(:column_name) works, but how do I iterate over an array of column names?

```
react = []
fields = [reactivity_1, reactivity_2, reactivity_3, reactivity_4]
fields.each do |field|
  puts "Parsing #{field}"
  Raw.all.uniq.pluck(field).each do |r|
    unless react.include? r
      puts "Adding #{r} to Array."
      react << r
    else
      puts "#{r} Exists."
    end
  end
end

Error:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `reactivity_1' for main:Object
```

Comment: Since you're calling `uniq` on the fetch it shouldn't be necessary to check that your local array includes the thing. They're unique already.

Comment: There may be duplicate values in each column. So uniq.pluck(:reactivity_1) would be Human, Rat, Mouse. uniq.pluck(:reactivity_2) would be Human, Chimpanzee. I want to avoid pushing Human to the array twice.

Comment: It sounds like you've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if those are your actual column names. A proper relational structure would help here, where that record `has_many :reactivities`. In any case, `react << r` and then later `react.flatten.uniq` can handle it.

Comment: The supplied data set violates normalization. What I'm attempting is to do is parse a flat, unrelational data set, into a relational structure. Unfortunately the supplied data is a complete mess.

Comment: Hopefully fixing it isn't too painful because this sounds pretty awful. The `flatten.uniq` approach is pretty easy if you're not dealing with tons of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make the column names strings or symbols, like this Ruby thinks it is a local varaible or method.

```
react = Set.new
fields = [:reactivity_1, :reactivity_2, :reactivity_3, :reactivity_4]
fields.each do |field|
  puts "Parsing #{field}"
  Raw.all.uniq.pluck(field).each do |r|
    react << r
  end
end
```

If you want to make sure that a collection does not contain duplicate, you can use a `Set`:

```
require "set"
set = Set.new
set << "foo"
set << "bar"
set << "bar"
puts set.size #> 2
```

I've rewritten your code sample to use `Set`.

Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps there is an easier way to get the data out of the DB.

Comment: You can also use `%i[ ... ]` for long lists of symbols, like `%[ reactivity1 reactivity_2 ]` etc.

Comment: Derp. Thanks much! That worked. I'm trying to populate a Join table. I've been supplied a spreadsheet with columns of reactivity_1, reactivity_2, etc. and I need to pull out the unique values to populate a reference table, and then populate the Join table with the reactivity ID and the Item ID.